# Getting the base path of the routes configured

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, twirl

I have two route file that make up the routes configuration

first file:
admin.routes

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~
#
# API ENDPOINTS

POST    /v1/login                      @controllers.Authentication.login()
POST    /v1/logout                      @controllers.Authentication.logout()
```

2nd file:
routes

```
# Route
# This file defines the base path route
# ~~~~
#
# API ENDPOINTS

->      /admin     admin.Routes
```

Is there a way in the twirl template that I could get the "/admin" part of the configuration? It doesn't seem to be too well documented.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `requestHeader.uri` in Play Java to get the path in your template:

```
<p>Current page: @requestHeader.uri</p>
```

So if you are accessing `http://localhost:9000/admin/v1/login`, you will get

```
<p>Current page: /admin/v1/login<p>
```

You can now use something like `@requestHeader.uri.startsWith("/admin")` to check if this template is being accessed by an `admin` url

Comment: Hi Salem, Thanks for the tip. Is there anyway I can only get /admin? any ideas?